# When the global optimal is outside of the constraint set, what will be the demand?

Tags: utility, consumer-theory, optimization, demand

$u:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a quasi-concave utility function so the indifference curves are convex.

$a,b\in\mathbb R^n$ are two points. Our budget set is the (one-dimensional) segment $[a,b]$ that connects $a$ and $b$.

Given: $$x^*=\arg\max_{x\in[a,b]}u(x)$$

Let $b'$ be a point in the segment $[a,x^*]$. That is: $b'=\lambda a+(1-\lambda)x^*$ for any $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Prove that:

$$b'=\arg\max_{x\in[a,b']}u(x)$$

Graphically this result is very straight forward but I don't know how to mathematically prove it.

I think we could start of proving that $u(\lambda a+(1-\lambda) x^*)$ is monotonically decreasing with $\lambda$.

Are there named theory related?

Comment: By $\mathbb R^n$ did you simply mean the real line $\mathbb R$? The notation $[a,b]$ implies $b>a$, but if we take $n=2$ and the budget set be the line segment connecting $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$, then it's not obvious which point should be $a\in\mathbb R^2$ and which be $b\in\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @HerrK. Either way, the argument holds geometrically, I think. The notation is a bit unconventional I suppose but it is pretty clear that $a,b$ are any $\mathbb R^n$ points.

Comment: I know the result is unaffected. I'm just saying that maybe you should be a little more careful with notations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Argue that, given your assumptions on the utility function, $x^*$ is the essentially unique (and hence global) maximum. (You need this because there may be local maxima when the assumptions on the utility function is relaxed - this will violate the proposition you're trying to prove).
2. Now simply use the definition of global optima: for any $x\leq x^*$, $u(x)\leq u(x^*)$. This should be enough to give you the result.

Comment: Upvoted but if the optima are not unique but a convex set (in this case a connected segment), then the proposition seems still hold. If the indifference curve is convex instead of strictly convex, then the optima can be a convex set.

Comment: Thats why I mentioned essentially unique. Because all the optima in the convex set will be payoff-equivalent.

Comment: Ok I see. I am not sure how to go from $u(x)\leq u(x^*)$ to $u(x)\leq u(b)$. Could you please help with it?

Comment: Assume part 1 has been proved. Then pick any $y\in[a,b^{\prime}]$. Then we know. that $y\leq b^{\prime}$ and $b^{\prime}\leq x^*$ (by definition of $b^{\prime}$). Since $u(.)$ is increasing in the interval $[a,x^*]$, $y\leq b^{\prime} \leq x^* \implies u(y)\leq u(b^{\prime})\leq u(x^*)$. Thus $u(b^{\prime})\geq u(y)$ for all $y\in[1,b^{\prime}]$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but if $n>1$ (i.e. more than 2 dimensions), then it is not necessarily that $y\leq b'$ as $a$ and $b$ are any points. I am sorry that the question was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: If you are working on a high dimension plane, clarify what your set of alternatives is: is it a line between points $a$ and $b$, or is it the 2-dimensional cube $\times_{I=1,\ldots n}[a_i,b_i]$? For the latter $y_i\leq b$ is still pretty much valid.

Comment: $[a,b]$ is the one-dimensional segment connecting $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I think it is easy to generalize your result into higher dimensional space because we can just rotate the x-axis such that your proof can be repeated. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. For a line segment, yeah.  Easy way to do that is just convert the utility to a single dimension: Define the preference relation $\succsim_R$ represented by the utility function $U:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $U(\lambda) = u\big(a\lambda+b(1-\lambda)\big)$.